# AngularJS in Laravel using Elixir

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-elixir

I am trying to setup a Laravel and Angular application. I wanted to place my work files under `resources/assets/js` and then use webpack and elixir to compile those code and create a single app.js file in my public directory. But I am not sure how to do that? Can anyone guide me with a step based approach for it?

Comment: I could help, but I use gulp only. Not using webpack yet as most of my projects are still using gulp. So if later on, no one helps you with webpack, I could give you my gulp setup for angular JS inside Laravel.

Comment: Sure. I setup the bower.json and pulled in angular and bootstrap. Now I am confused how to use gulp and combine into single js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't do this from scratch but there is a package that uses lumen, angular2. Providing a link for the same so anyone with the same problem can be benefited. Link: [anvel.io](http://anvel.io)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a `gulp` only process**

No webpack used. Please anyone can rewrite this with `Laravel Mix` I would really appreciate.

1- Install npm modules

```
`npm i --S bower gulp gulp-concat gulp-uglify`
```

2- Install Angular with bower

```
bower install --save angular angular-sanitize angular-ui-router
```

3- Now that you have your angular assets in `bower_components`, create a file at the root of your project to load all vendors. Let's create `/vendor.json`

```
[
    "bower_components/angular/angular.min.js",
    "bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js",
    "bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"
]
```

Add all your vendors to that file. Bower or Npm vendors. Anything you download that is not part of your code.

4- Go to `/gulpfile.js` and add a task

```
var gulp   = require('gulp),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify  = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('vendorjs', function() {
    var source = require('./vendorjs.json');
    return gulp.src(source)
    .pipe(concat('vendors.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/js'))
});
```

That task will compile all vendors assets to `/public/assets/js/vendors.min.js`

5- In `resources/assets/js`, create following directories `controllers`, `modules` and the file `app.js`. Inside of `app.js` do

```
// 'resources/assets/js/app.js'
(function(){
    angular
    .module('myApp', ['app.core', 'app.controllers']);
})();
```

6- In the `modules` directory create `core/module.js`. This is the core module where you load all external modules loaded via bower or npm.

```
// 'resources/assets/js/modules/core/module.js'
(function(){
    angular
    .module('app.core', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
})();
```

7- Still in the `modules` directory create `controllers/module.js`. All your controllers will be bound to this module.

```
// 'resources/assets/js/modules/controllers/module.js'
(function(){
    angular
    .module('app.controllers', []);
})();
```

8- Now you can write your controllers like this

```
// 'resources/assets/js/controllers/home.js'
(function(){
    angular
    .module('app.controllers')
    .controller('HomeController', Controller);

    //Use injection for assets minification 
    HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
    function HomeController($scope, $http)
    {
        var vm = this;
        activate();

        function activate()
        {
            vm.sayHi = function() {
                console.log('Hi');
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

9- If you want to define routes

```
// 'resources/assets/js/modules/routes/routes.js'
(function(){
    angular
    .module('app.routes', [])
    .config(routesConfig);

    //Use injection for assets minification 
    routesConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function routesConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
    {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        ...
    }
})();
```

10 - Create angular task in gulpfile

```
gulp.task('angular', function() {
    var root = 'resources/assets/js';
    var source = [
        root + '/app.js',
        root + '/modules/**/*module.js',
        root + '/controllers/**/*js'
    ];

return gulp.src(source)
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify()) //comment this line when in development
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/js'))
});
```

I think that's it. I may have made one or 2 typos, but angular that's the gist of it. How I use gulp with laravel for angular